# Node: port some JSON processing logic to wasm, worth?

Tags: node.js, json, webassembly

In Node, does it make sense to port some logic to wasm for json manipulation operations in order for the algorithm to be quicker?

Comment: Is it causing performance problems right now?

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr Don't use WASM for JSON manipulation.

Setting up the WASM tooling is no small thing, and will likely require more ongoing troubleshooting and maintenance than lighter-weight solutions.

Wasm generally comes into its own when you need to do truly compute-intensive stuff like customized signal (image/video/audio) processing for your browser users or natively inside server-size Javascript environments.

If your purpose in doing this is avoiding overhead in JSON processing, you might consider looking for fast JSON packages on npm. [fast-json-stable-stringify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-json-stable-stringify) is an example.

You should also keep this in mind: V8 -- the open-source Javascript engine in nodejs, deno, and chromium -- is under active development by a large and highly competent team at Google. That engine includes the `JSON.` functions. Performance improvements show up in every release, and they're highly motivated to keep making things faster. JSON handling is one of those areas. If you roll your own, your code won't get any faster with the next release of V8/nodejs. If you use the stuff in V8, it might.

Take a look at this [dev summit presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ff4fgQxPaO0), for example. Maybe you can outsmart the V8 team. If so you should join them.

So, if you want to learn WASM, do something that will add interesting new capabilities to your personal toolbox.

Answer (score 2):

Unlikely. The V8 engine has a pretty good JIT compiler. If it is a hot path and properly written, it will become machine code anyway.